# Angular detect FormControl disabled state changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

If I'm implementing `ControlValueAccessor`, then the `setDisabledState` method is called for me on changes.

How do I accomplish the same thing if my component just attaches its own `FormGroup` to the parent form via providing `ControlContainer` and adding to that?

My use case here is that in the parent form, it's going to enable or disable the `FormGroup` based on overall permissions from the network call's data. However, in my child component, one specific `FormControl` should have a different state based on a different permission.

For example, the child component would look like so:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  protected readonly formGroup = ...
  readonly #parent = inject(FormGroupDirective)

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.#parent.form.addControl('child', this.formGroup)
  }

  // What I want then is this:
  disabledStateChanged(): void {
    const ctrl = this.formGroup.controls.special

    if (canEditSpecialField)
      ctrl.enable()
    else
      ctrl.disable()
  }
}
```

I don't want to implement that logic at the toplevel because then that breaks the whole point of this component knowing about its own `FormGroup`.